# How to import Access 2010 database (.accdb) into MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, import, ms-access

How to import Access 2010 database (.accdb) into MySQL. For example, I want to import my Product inventory database.accdb fully, how can I do that easily. Thanks.

Comment: Googling `How to import Access 2010 database (.accdb) into MySQL` shows a lot of promising hits

Comment: I have used this tool before - http://www.bullzip.com/products/a2m/info.php.  It is also easy to use ODBC to connect Access directly to your MySQL db and then copy data between them.

Comment: I used Bullzip for a while. I was very satisfied. But not anymore; it is giving me an error when I press "import". The error is very common (Error 50: File already open), many people posted the issue on the official web site but no one replied.

Answer (score 7):

There are many ways.

You can export Microsoft Access tables to CSV file and import that file in MySQL (little complicated but fastest way).

You can install MySQL ODBC driver and connect MySQL tables in access

You can save/export .accdb database to old access format and find tutorial for old version.